# IOS: SearchBar scrolls down - UISearchController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am following the steps to implement a searchBar ([google documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete?hl=en-419#get_place_predictions_programmatically)) which I have managed to realize but when pressing the text box to write the address the UISearchController is placed down, attaching images for further compression of the problem

[image]

[image]